# Show that the equilibrium point (r, 0) = (1,0) is not stable, even though all nearby solution tend to it (eventually).

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For $r' = r - r^3$, and $\theta' = sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})$, Find all equilibrium points.

I found that the equilibrium points are (1,$2m\pi$), (0,$2m\pi$),(-1,$2m\pi$) for m is a integer. Could anyone make sure this is right?

b) Show that the equilibrium point (r, 0) = (1,0) is not stable, even though all nearby solution tend to it (eventually).

My approach is
after linearized the system, it become  $r' = r $, and $\theta' = sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})$S So, the Jacobin matrix at (1,0) is

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\0& cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2}) =1
\end{array}\right)$$ 
So Both eigenvalues are 1. This is a source. However, as I use technology to see, at this point (1,0), the graph is more like one eigenvalue 0 and another eigenvalue is -1...I am wondering what wrong is my answer? Even the technology is right that one eigenvalue 0 and another eigenvalue is -1. Then, isn't it stable? How do I show this is not stable?

Answer (score 0):

The Jacobian matrix is:
$$
J(r,\theta)=\left(\begin{array}_1-3r^2 & 0\\0 & \sin(\theta)
\end{array}\right),
$$
Thus:
$$
J(1,0)=\left(\begin{array}_-2& 0\\0 & 0
\end{array}\right),
$$
and the eigenvalues are $0$ and $-2$.

Comment: based on your reasoning, it should be 1 = 2(1)^2 = -1?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. It is 1-3r^2, and valuating in 1 it is as high as -2. Thus one eigenvalue is with negative real part and one is null, so that you cannot apply a first order approximation.

Comment: How does this show that this is not stable? It is because linearized system does not work?

Comment: It is because you cannot apply linearisation theorem, i.e. it fails. So, trajectories still tend to approach the point (1,0), but it is not stable in a linear sense. When you have a zero eigenvalue you usually analise second order approximation

Comment: when you said, it fails... do you mean the linarized system does not accurately describe the nonlinear system at the equilibrium point?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Also, in mathematics, when you linearise, the eigenvalues must have non-null real part, otherwise second/higher order terms prevail on the first order ones.

Comment: what is non-null ?

Comment: Greater or lower than zero